# Avecto Privilege Guard - How to run from command line?

Tags: windows-7, windows, privileges

OS: Windows 7 Enterprise

PG is run via right clicking Windows Explorer when an executable is selected and selcting the Privilege Guard menu item.

Is there anyway to wrap this into a script\batch file so I don't have to remember to do this for certain apps?

Comment: I'd love to see an answer to this one. I had a look around in the registry but I couldn't work out what hook it is that controls this context menu item.

Comment: Please accept @MatthewPeters answer. It is correct. Win 7 tested true

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simple add `avecto` to the beginning of your call. For instance, if you want to run notepad.exe as avecto elevated, simply put the following in a `.cmd` file: `avecto notepad.exe`

Additionally, you can alter the shortcut properties by adding `avecto` as mentioned above.

Comment: Can you please share the location of the avecto.exe

Comment: Seems that avecto command is missing on latter versions, cannot find it anywhere

Answer (score 2):

Since avecto.bat is not available anymore you can use a general program requesting elevation like [Johannes Passing Elevate.exe](https://jpassing.com/2007/12/08/launch-elevated-processes-from-the-command-line/). Then just use elevate as you has used avecto, e.g.

```
elevate prog.exe
```

or

```
elevate -k script.cmd
```

As a nice side effect it works in arbitrary environments.

Duplicate of  [Programmatically execute a program using Avecto Privilege Guard?](https://superuser.com/questions/1026718/programmatically-execute-a-program-using-avecto-privilege-guard/1295571#1295571)

Comment: This does not launch DefendPoint for me, it only pops up the UAC dialog asking for an admin account.  Are Privilege Guard and DefendPoint two separate products?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend companies staying away from the current product,  as it has problems with large executables.  When Right clicking it can take almost an hour to get context menu ( if it doesnt lock up the machine ).   And since there does seem to be a way to launch an exe with PG on the command line, u may not be able to install required programs.   We will need a real admin user to install these programs.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).