# Debug a program with elevated priveges with Avecto Privilege Guard -

Tags: windows, privileges

I am debugging a program that needs admin access in a shop that normally uses avecto privilege guard for admin level access.

Starting visual studio with avecto does not seem to pass on the elevation to the program being debugged.

I was hoping that there was someway besides the context menu to start a program with avecto.

[This SuperUser question](http://avecto-privilege-guard) seems to indicate you could use the command `avecto` as a prefix on the command line to run elevated.  I had hoped to change the Debugging properties in VisualStudio to run the program that way.

changing 'Command' from `$(TargetPath)` to `avecto $(TargetPath)`

But alas, `avecto` doesn't seem to work that way on this system, not can I find an absolute path to something like `avecto.bat` or `avecto.exe` that might implement it.  Nor could I find what the context menu was doing with `regedit`

Is there some new way of doing the `avecto` from the command line, or otherwise starting the program under debug somehow  with `avecto`?

[Avecto Privilege Guard - How to run from command line?](https://superuser.com/questions/965737/avecto-privilege-guard-how-to-run-from-command-line?s=2|4.7754)

( EDIT: the local IT security people gave up and gave me local admin. Rare occurrence )

Answer (score 0):

1. SHIFT + Right-Click on the VS Shortcut.
2. Click “Run Elevated with DefendPoint”
3. Provide your password when requested.

You should then see VS running with Admin rights.

Comment: I tried running VS with elevated privilege back then, but that elevation was not being inherited by the program being debugged.  I did put that in the question, but thanks anyway @PaulLydon